# How to change the amount of building threads in Xcode?

Tags: c++, multithreading, xcode, compilation, building

I'm building a couple of C++ files in xcode that take a lot of memory to compile (+1 GB / file). Because I do this on my dual core laptop, xcode uses 2 threads for building. The two threads will eventually be building the files that take a lot of memory simultaneously so the system suffers memory starvation and the compilation grinds to a near halt.

A sufficient solution for me would be to force Xcode to use only one build thread. Does anybody know a way to change how many build threads Xcode uses?

For those who are interested, the C++ files contain a sizable boost::spirit::qi parser.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The number of threads Xcode is using to perform tasks is controlled by `PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks` option. You can change it with the following command: - `defaults write com.apple.Xcode <key> <value>`. For example:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks 8
```

See [Xcode User Defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html) for more details.

There are also many other ways to speed up a compilation, from precompiled headers to distributed builds. Read [Reducing Build Times](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2190/_index.html) for more information on this.

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. Also the part on reducing build times is an interesting read.

Comment: Try this one defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks ` `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` `

Answer (score 13):

With XCode 5, you can use `-parallelizeTargets` and  `-jobs NUMBER` with `xcodebuild`. According to `xcodebuild --help`:

> ```
> -parallelizeTargets     build independent targets in parallel
> -jobs NUMBER            specify the maximum number of concurrent build operations
> ```

Comment: With the new build system in Xcode 9+ enabled, `-parallelizeTargets` appears to be redundant and, in my tests, has no effect on compile time.

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 4 you must set the IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks user default, for example:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4
```

Note the "dt".  This won't affect xcodebuild on the command line.  To do that, use something like

```
xcodebuild -IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks=4 ...
```

(See http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Apr/msg00403.html and http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Jul//msg00377.html )

Comment: This seems to no longer work with Xcode 7 - any ideas how to specify the number of jobs now?

Answer (score 1):

A single build task should never do the same work twice, and certainly not simultaneously! Factor out the massive chunk of common code into a static library so it can be recompiled only when it changes. Set a target dependency in your application on the static library and link in the static library product. Changes to the rest of your application will then no longer require rebuilding the static library, which should speed up build times tremendously.

Try to exhaust all project-level solutions before manipulating Xcode as a whole. It is too easy to cripple Xcode to using only a single thread and forget to change it back when you move on to a new project. The [*Xcode User Default Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/000-Introduction/Introduction.html) documents many options that are not exposed via the Preferences interface, including:

- **PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks** (positive integer)

  This allows you to limit Xcode to using only *n* build threads on every project it compiles.
- **BuildSystemCacheSizeInMegabytes** (positive integer, default 1024)
- **BuildSystemCacheMinimumRemovalAgeInHours** (positive integer, default 24)

  Upping the PCH cache size and retention time could help speed up your builds.

Comment: It's not the same work, they're actually several files with huge compilation memory usage. The same files are also built twice because Xcode builds both a 64-bit and a 32-bit version and then merges them afterwards. A static lib won't help me much as I'm currently working on those files. Thanks for your answer though, the PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks is exactly what I needed. A more permanent solution would be to add some RAM to my PC, I didn't realize that compilation tasks could take that much memory.

Comment: Does anyone know if BuildSystemCacheSizeInMegabytes still has any effect?